# WampServer 2.4, All access

Tags: php, mysql, wampserver

So, I've been searching around on how to allow other so, not just on my LAN, to look at my server(so I can fully use this app http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/). But I can never seem to get it to work. And it seems that everything I find is different from the one before. Is there any place where I can find a set way to allow others to access my server? It is Wampserver (32 bits & PHP 5.4) 2.4 or could someone explain to me how.

Thank you in advance,

Tyler

Answer (score 0):

This really depends upon how and from where you are running your app.

If you are running out of `\wamp\www` or `\wamp\www\a_folder` then you should be able to use the Wampmanager menus ( thats the green icon that sits in the System Tray ) like so:-

```
wampmanager -> Put Online
```

Now there was a little bug in WAMPServer 2.4 that causes this menu function not to work so I suggest you have a look at this document which has a fix for this problem and suggestions for many other tidy-ups for the 2.4 release. [WAMPServer 2.4 What to do after installing](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,119754)

Now of course you can just manually change your `httpd.conf` file, again using the wampmanager menus to make sure you edit the correct file.

```
wampmanager -> Apache -> httpd.conf
```

This will open the `httpd.conf` file in an editor, probably notepad.

Find this in that file:-

```
# onlineoffline tag - do not remove
Require local
```

And change it to

```
# onlineoffline tag - do not remove
Require all granted
```

Yours may look like this if you have not made the changes suggested in the document mentioned above.

```
#    Require all granted
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from all
     Allow from 127.0.0.1
     Allow from ::1
     Allow from localhost
```

But regardless change it to what is suggested above

If you have created a Virtual Host then this change can be done manually in the Virtual Host definition just the same way.

Of course once you have done that, you also need to `Port Forward` your router to allow traffic on Port 80 from the internet through your router and to your PC running the WAMPServer.
This is quite a handy site as it contains instructions on how to do the port forwarding for lots of different routers. [PortForward.com](http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/)