# WAMP - Onlineoffline tag (putting wamp online)

Tags: php, apache, wamp

I am having problems editing the `#onlineoffline tag` in the `httpd.conf` file from WAMP. The server will not go online (or be accessed by any other computer on the network). Before the new version, the previous .conf file contained a statement like:

```
Order deny, allow
Allow from all
```

In this new version, the `#onlineoffline` tag is:

```
onlineoffline tag - don't remove
Require local
```

I have done what was suggested from multiple stackOverflow threads like **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21194101/wampserver-2-4-all-access/21231273#21231273)**, using `Require all granted`. This only causes the WAMP icon to stay yellow. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: check the port 80 it must be available , try to exit from skype if you are using it, and then restart wamp

Comment: Before altering the `httpd.conf` testing port 80 will work fine, but after altering it, testing port 80 will return `your port 80 is not actually used.`

Comment: I have uninstalled WAMP serveral times already hoping i have made a mistake in altering the httpd.conf, but with no luck

Comment: Post the section of your httpd.conf file that you changed.

Comment: @SarahKemp I changed this, `#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
Require local`
to this:

`#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
Require all granted`

Comment: And if you change it back to `Require local` WAMP goes green?

Answer (score 1):

Edit this section of your httpd.conf file as follows

```
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
    #Require local
    Require all granted
```

If you are listening to a port (e.g. 4140), ensure that you edit this section of your httpd.conf as follows

```
# Change this to Listen on specific IP addresses as shown below to
# prevent Apache from glomming onto all bound IP addresses.
#
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 0.0.0.0:80
Listen [::0]:80
Listen 0.0.0.0:4140
Listen [::0]:4140
```

Of course you must have added the port as a new inbound rule in your Firewall